# Simulating a global variable in MPI

Tags: synchronization, mpi

*I tried to google but hasn't found the solution*

The short question is the following: is it possible to simulate a global variable in MPI so that it doesn't require processes to wait too much.

Now the long story. I want to implement a branch-and-bound algorithm for the unicost set covering problem with MPI. For that, I need a way for each process to know the current global optimum found by any of the other processes so far—so that the process can stop branching if its current solution becomes worse than the global optimum found so far. Some kind of a (synchronised) global variable would be perfect for that.

What I want to do in my algorithm is something like following. Let us say there is a global variable `curr_global_min`. Each process during its work from time to time reads this variable and—if the current optimum it has found so far is smaller that `curr_global_min`—updates this global variable with his local minimum. I anticipate that updating the global minimum is **a rather rare** event (except for the very beginning of the algorithm).

Obviously, I want to do this without too much of computational time wasted. On the other hand, I can tolerate some **delays** in updating, that is, `curr_global_min` not necessarily needs to be *immediately* sent to all the processes—provided this saves total computational time.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the size of the problem I want to try to solve: the total number of elements is 9740685 and I have 759 subsets of size 504152, 2576  subsets of size 49140, and 759 subsets of size 4096. I still wonder if it's feasible to calculate this on a cluster in a week.

Comment: If you can accept some delay, you can post a non blocking receive (`MPI_Recv(..., source=MPI_ANY_SOURCE, ...)` on all ranks. When the *global variable* should be updated, simply send the new value to all the ranks. All the ranks should periodically check if the *global variable* has been updated with `MPI_Test()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a f***ing more complicated problem that one could think at first glance. But it is also a very common issue when you need some global synchronization which depend on the state/computation of a single rank. Sadly there is no "holy grail" solution. There is multitudes of solutions, each have advantages and drawbacks... lets give you the two most used one:

1) Brut force...
Each time you verify if there is a new minimum you compute the global minimum with a reduce... This solution will work at 100%, but involve communication which are most of the time useless...

2) Looking at one sided communication: This will allow you to do exactly what you want. But you will need to set up some mechanism to "block" computation when you update the minimum.

A long quote from this doc: 
http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-onesided.html

Above, you saw point-to-point operations of the two-sided type: they require the co-operation of a sender and receiver. This co-operation could be loose: you can post a receive with MPI_ANY_SOURCE as sender, but there had to be both a send and receive call. In this section, you will see one-sided communication routines where a process can do a `put' or`get' operation, writing data to or reading it from another processor, without that other processor's involvement.

In one-sided MPI operations, also known as RDMA or RMA operations, there are still two processes involved: the origin , which is the process that originates the transfer, whether this is a `put' or a`get', and the target whose memory is being accessed. Unlike with two-sided operations, the target does not perform an action that is the counterpart of the action on the origin.

That does not mean that the origin can access arbitrary data on the target at arbitrary times. First of all, one-sided communication in MPI is limited to accessing only a specifically declared memory area on the target: the target declares an area of user-space memory that is accessible to other processes. This is known as a window . Windows limit how origin processes can access the target's memory: you can only `get' data from a window or`put' it into a window; all the other memory is not reachable from other processes.

The alternative to having windows is to use distributed shared memory or virtual shared memory : memory is distributed but acts as if it shared. The so-called PGAS languages such as UPC use this model. The MPI RMA model makes it possible to lock a window which makes programming slightly more cumbersome, but the implementation more efficient.

Within one-sided communication, MPI has two modes: active RMA and passive RMA. In active RMA , or active target synchronization , the target sets boundaries on the time period (the `epoch') during which its window can be accessed. The main advantage of this mode is that the origin program can perform many small transfers, which are aggregated behind the scenes. Active RMA acts much like asynchronous transfer with a concluding Waitall .

In passive RMA , or passive target synchronization , the target process puts no limitation on when its window can be accessed. ( PGAS languages such as UPC are based on this model: data is simply read or written at will.) While intuitively it is attractive to be able to write to and read from a target at arbitrary time, there are problems. For instance, it requires a remote agent on the target, which may interfere with execution of the main thread, or conversely it may not be activated at the optimal time. Passive RMA is also very hard to debug and can lead to strange deadlocks.

My choice would be implement 1) then if it reeally generate a big bottleneck, then once your entire code works implement 2) using active RMA (and if you like to get pissed from debugging during weeks, use passive one :-) )